# Angularjs and route authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a AngularJS project with Asp Web API as backend. I have a login controller in angularjs that make a signin request to web api to request a token and if the user correctly logged in i set a variable in angularjs.

Now how can i prevent to load a route if the user isn't logged in? How, in the routeProvider can i prevent to load a route based on the setted variable?

```
gestionale.config(
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
        when('/personale', {
           templateUrl: 'View/people.html',
           controller: 'mainController',
           !!What to put here????!!!
    })
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will want to listen for the `$locationChangeStart` event and prevent the default behavior if the user is not authenticated.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    if (!vm.loggedIn()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually see patterns like:

```
gestionale.config(
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
        when('/personale', {
           templateUrl: 'View/people.html',
           controller: 'mainController',
           options: {
               accessRole: 'admin'
           }
    })
 });
```

where control flows for 'userRole' will be handled by a User or Auth Service and then you can use [Ben Felda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130908/ben-felda)'s method above to desist access as the routes change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'resolve' property.

```
gestionale.config(
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
        when('/personale', {
           templateUrl: 'View/people.html',
           controller: 'mainController',
           resolve: userLoggedIn()
    })
 });
```

The userLoggedIn function would then handle the authentication promise and only resolve to the location when the promise is returned. This would also allow you to bounce them back to the login if the promise was rejected.